# A symbol name was expected! (near "'{"y":0,"x":0,"h":0,"z":0}'" at position 436)

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `houselocations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coords` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `owned` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tier` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `garage` text NOT NULL, '{"y":0,"x":0,"h":0,"z":0}',
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What's `'{"y":0,"x":0,"h":0,"z":0}'` supposed to be? (column name, data type, ???)

Comment: coords for fivem

Comment: data i think maybe

Comment: And what is "fivem"? [Edit] the question and make clear what the table you want to create should be like. Invest a little work, if you want help and don't leave everything open.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax issues in the create before `ENGINE`, the structure should be:

```
CREATE TABLE `houselocations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coords` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `owned` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tier` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `garage` text NOT NULL DEFAULT ('{"y":0,"x":0,"h":0,"z":0}')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

With that added, checking the create:

```
show create table houselocations;
```

Gives:

```
Table           Create Table
                CREATE TABLE `houselocations` (
                  `id` int NOT NULL,
                  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `coords` text,
houselocations    `owned` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
                  `price` int DEFAULT NULL,
                  `tier` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
                  `garage` text NOT NULL DEFAULT (_utf8mb4'{"y":0,"x":0,"h":0,"z":0}')
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Insert a record:

```
INSERT INTO houselocations (id, garage) VALUES (1, '{"y":20,"x":20,"h":10,"z":1}');
```

Get the record:

```
SELECT * FROM houselocations;
```

The result:

```
id  name    label   coords  owned   price   tier    garage
1   null    null    null    null    null    null    {"y":20,"x":20,"h":10,"z":1}
```

Example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c9e36697e418b2ff48e20e9d10bb0b4)